# JMeter: "Communication Link Failure" in Response Data

Tags: jdbc, request, jmeter

I am trying to execute JDBC request but following error appears:

*Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.*